# Saving the html file's current state?

Tags: javascript, html, button, save

So I am running some tests with JS and HTML right now, and one of the things I am doing is appending text to the page with JS every time the button is pressed. How do I keep the html the same after reloading the page? Is there a way to save it's current state so the added text doesn't go away? I'm sorry if this was answered before, I couldn't find any answers on this, nor do I know if it's possible. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <HTML> 
<HEADER> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexcss.css">

    <center> 
    <b> 
<TITLE> </TITLE> 
 <div id='parentID'> 

 </div>
<script> 
prompt("prompting");

var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Do Something"; 
// 2. Append somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);

// 3. Add event handler
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('parentID'); 
        div.innerHTML += 'Extra stuff';
});
</script>
    <h1>

    </h1>
    </b> 
    </center> 

    </HEADER> 
<BODY> 




</BODY>
```

Comment: The proper way is to use code on the sever to remember state. But with only a clientside solution, you have cookies or localstorage.

Comment: Please fix your HTML code properly.

Comment: @epascarello I'm assuming you meant server, I'm currently messing around with FTP file storage. My website's files are stored there. Is it possible if you can give an example or a reference to where I can learn how to have the page's state remembered. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you need some sort of serverside language to write the files. AKA PHP, Node, Java, etc.  It would not be wise to figure out how to push to an FTP site with JavaScript since the credentials would have to be made public in the code.

Answer (score 2):

use localStorage

```js
set()
document.body.innerHTML += Math.random()
save()

function save() {
  localStorage.setItem("html", document.body.innerHTML)
}

function set() {
  let content = localStorage.getItem("html")
  if(content) {
    document.body.innerHTML = content
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  hi
</body>
```

Comment: Would localstorage refer to the website's FTP File storage?